# How to keep track of the subject/entity in a sentence?

Tags: natural-language-processing, bert, sentiment-analysis

I'm working on Sentiment Analysis, using HuggingFace to perform sentiment analysis on articles

```
 classifier = pipeline('sentiment-analysis', model="nlptown/bert-base-multilingual-uncased-sentiment")
 classifier(['We are very happy to show you the  Transformers library.',  "We hope you don't hate it."])
```

This returns

> label: POSITIVE, with score: 0.9998

> label: NEGATIVE, with score: 0.5309

Now I'm trying to understand how to keep track of a subject when performing the sentiment analysis.

Suppose I'm given a sentence like this.

> StackExchange is a great website. It helps users answer questions.  Hopefully, someone will help answer this question.

I would like to keep track of the subject when performing sentiment analysis. In the example above, in the 2nd sentence 'it' refers to 'StackExchange'. I would like to be able to do track a subject between sentences.

Now, I could try to manually try to parse this by finding the verb and trying to figure find the phrase that comes before it. However, it doesn't sound like a very safe or accurate way to find the subject.

Alternatively, I could train similar to a Named Entity Recognition. However, finding a dataset for this is very hard, and training it would be very time-consuming.

How can I keep track of an entity within an article?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is known as [coreference resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coreference#Coreference_resolution). More specifically, this example is [anaphora resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphora_(linguistics)#Anaphora_resolution_%E2%80%93_centering_theory). The short answer is that this is an open research question and there is no well-established solution.

You mentioned [Hugging Face](https://github.com/huggingface) in your question. The [neuralcoref](https://spacy.io/universe/project/neuralcoref) module in spaCy is itself from Hugging Face (note the reflexive anaphor used for emphasis in this sentence). If you're not a spaCy kind of person, then there's also [Stanford's](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dcoref.shtml) [CoreNLP](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/) in Java that has coreference resolution. A [Python wrapper](https://github.com/dasmith/stanford-corenlp-python) is also available.

I also wanted to address a couple other topics you mentioned. You are right in that they're all somewhat connected. But you need to scope down your goal/research question because what you're aiming to achieve is too difficult for a first task. Named entity recognition, constituency parsing, and sentiment analysis. Pick just one to focus on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'm new to this field so this information is very useful for my research.  I saw CoreNLP and was debating on using it.  I think I'll need to make some hybrid solution, which uses CoreNLP to analyize the subject, and some savvy rules to maintain track of the subject

Comment: You're welcome! Part of the difficulty in getting start with NLP is understanding the correct terms to call things. One you know the right term you can often find useful answers.